# Why can't I call my Handlebars partial inside #each?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

While refactoring some code I got this problem: When applying a Handlebars template that uses a partial, it complains about `You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed function ...`. The function is this:

```
function (context, options) {
  options = options || {};
  var namespace = options.partial ? options : env,
      helpers,
      partials;

  if (!options.partial) {
    helpers = options.helpers;
    partials = options.partials;
  }
  var result = templateSpec.call(
        container,
        namespace, context,
        helpers,
        partials,
        options.data);

  if (!options.partial) {
    checkRevision(container.compilerInfo);
  }

  return result;
}
```

What I did:

A partial is used to iterate over a list (called members) to build a `ul` of checkboxes. I found out I needed to make a list of lists and put the call to the partial inside an `#each` and updated the template input.

I have this:

Template:

```
...
{{#each hierarchy.levels}}
<ul>
{{> mypartial}}
</ul>
{{/each}}
```

Partial (simplified):

```
{{#each members}}
<li>{{this.id}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

I've checked that each `hierarchy.levels` in my data structure has a `members` list.

If I replace the `#each` in my template with `#with hierarchy.levels.[0]` (for instance) it works but it won't work when iterating over `levels`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. One of the 2nd level lists were empty (ie zero items) which led to Handlebars rendering it as an empty string which again led to Handlebars thinking that something was false and trying to render the partial as a regular template.